# Spring boot how to store multiple sessions in a web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-applications

I am attempting to make a web app where the user is required to login via Reddit. For this I am using JRAW, where the main object used is RedditClient.

I am slightly confused how I should handle tracking these multiple clients for the users who are logged in. I have a working application, but I think I'm going about storing these the wrong way.

**Auth.class**

```
public class Auth {

    private static final String URL = "http://localhost:4200/";

    private final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
    private final RedditClient redditClient = getDefaultRedditClient();
    private final Credentials credentials = getWebappCreds();
    private final URL authUrl = getClientAuthURL();

    public UUID getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public URL getAuthUrl(){
        return authUrl;
    }

    public AuthStatus getOAuthStatus(){
        return redditClient.getOAuthHelper().getAuthStatus();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public RedditClient getRedditClient(){
        return redditClient;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Credentials getWebappCreds(){
        return Credentials.webapp("<WEB_APP_ID>", "<WEB_APP_SECRET>", URL);
    }

    private URL getClientAuthURL(){
        URL url = redditClient.getOAuthHelper().getAuthorizationUrl(credentials, true, "history");
        return url;
    }

    public void auth(String state, String code) throws NetworkException, OAuthException, IllegalStateException {
        System.out.println("auth - state: " + state + ", code: " + code);
        String url = URL + "?state=" + state + "&code=" + code; 
        System.out.println("auth - url: " + url);
        auth(url);
    }

    private void auth(String redirectURL) throws NetworkException, OAuthException, IllegalStateException {
        OAuthData data = redditClient.getOAuthHelper().onUserChallenge(redirectURL, credentials);
        redditClient.authenticate(data);
    }

    private static RedditClient getDefaultRedditClient(){
        UserAgent myUserAgent = UserAgent.of("desktop", "io.rj93.reddit.search", "v0.1", "rj93");
        return new RedditClient(myUserAgent);
    }

}
```

**AuthController.class**

```
package io.rj93.reddit.search.server;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import net.dean.jraw.http.NetworkException;
import net.dean.jraw.http.oauth.OAuthException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthController {

    private static ConcurrentMap<String, Auth> auths = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Auth>();

    @RequestMapping("/auth")
    public Auth getAuth(){
        Auth auth = new Auth();
        auths.put(auth.getId().toString(), auth);
        return auth;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Auth authenticate(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) throws NetworkException, OAuthException, IllegalStateException{
        Auth auth = auths.get(payload.get("id"));
        auth.auth(payload.get("state"), payload.get("code"));
        return auth;
    }

}
```

The way it works is the website requests a new auth at `getAuth`, which creates a new reddit client and begins the auth process. This is stored in a Map, with the key being a UUID generated, which is returned to the user and sent in all further requests to the server. The website redirects to reddit to allow the user to grant permissions, and is then redirected to my website, where the values to authenticate are sent to the server in `authenticate`.

How should I actually be storing this? The library doesn't allow me to instantiate a RedditClient using preset data, so I have to go through this process of redirecting to reddit, etc.